# Nested model in R

Tags: r, statistics, nested, mixed, lmer

I'm having a huge problem with a nested model I am trying to fit in R.

I have response time experiment with 2 conditions with 46 people each and 32 measures each. I would like measures to be nested within people and people nested within conditions, but I can't get it to work.

The code I thought should make sense was:

```
nestedmodel <- lmer(responsetime ~ 1 + condition + 
 (1|condition:person) + (1|person:measure), data=dat)
```

However, all I get is an error:

```
Error in checkNlevels(reTrms$flist, n = n, control) : 
  number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations
```

Unfortunately, I do not even know where to start looking what the problem is here. 
Any ideas? Please, please, please? =)
Cheers!

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data. Make sure you have enough data to estimate all those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This might be more appropriate on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com), but: `lme4` is trying to tell you that one or more of your random effects is confounded with the residual variance.  As you've described your data, I don't quite see why: you should have 2*46*32=2944 total observations, 2*46=92 combinations of `condition` and `person`, and 46*32=1472 combinations of `measure` and `person`.

If you do

```
lf <- lFormula(responsetime ~ 1 + condition + 
                (1|condition:person) + (1|person:measure), data=dat)
```

and then

```
lapply(lf$reTrms$Ztlist,dim)
```

to look at the transposed random-effect design matrices for each term, what do you get?  You *should* (based on your description of your data) see that these matrices are 1472 by 2944 and 92 by 2944, respectively.

As @MrFlick says, a reproducible example would be nice. Other things you could show us are:

- fit the model anyway, using `lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE="ignore")` to ignore the test, and show us the results (especially the random effects variances and the statement of the numbers of groups)
- show us the results of `with(dat,table(table(interaction(condition,person)))` to give information on the number of replicates per combination (and similarly for `measure`)